# Hypograph of a quasiconcave function

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

If $f$ is a quasiconcave function, is its hypograph necessarily a convex set? My intuition says yes, but somehow I feel that this is not true, does anybody has a conterexample if the statement is not true?

Comment: Hi, can you define Hypograph?!

Comment: The hypograph (or subgraph) of a function is composed of all of the points on or below the graph of a function.

Comment: Is it the region delimited by the graph of the function, including the graph?

Comment: Yes, everything "below" the graph of the function, including the graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=-x^3$. Then $f$ is quasi-concave because $-f$ is quasi-convex since all of the sets $\{x\in\mathbb{R}:-f(x)\leq c\}$ are convex. But neither the epigraph nor the hypograph of $f$ are convex sets.

Comment: Thanks, you're absolutely right.